# Twilio programmable video zoom in camera

Tags: javascript, camera, twilio, webrtc

I am using twilio video javascript sdk in a browser (or mobile webview). It works just fine, both ends publish their tracks. But I have not found any way for a user to zoom in his/hers camera exept from a custom css solution. Is there any "native" way to zoom in a camera that is powering the published track in twilio video/webrtc?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Actually, the `navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints().zoom` is true in all cases which means it is indeed supported by webview but the `track.mediaStreamTrack.getCapabilities()` does not have the zoom property when in android webview. When in android chrome it works just fine. Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a relatively new API for pan-tilt-zoom that works with getUserMedia.
In a nutshell you should be able to use

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: {zoom: true}})
```

and then use MediaStreamTrack.applyConstraint to change the zoom.
See [the web.dev](https://web.dev/camera-pan-tilt-zoom/) article for the details (as well as pitfalls)

Comment: I checked this out, but unfortunatelly the zoom does not work on android webview that is my target. On chrome mobile though it works fine.

Comment: I added an edit, tell me if you know anything else. Thanks.

Comment: I believe it has to do with the permissions on the webview. the navigator.permissions is undefined there so maybe the native permission it asks does not know about ptz access

Comment: you might need to file a chrome bug. This scenario probably wasn't tested